# Possible bug with test users and page access tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, testing, access-token

Possible Facebook bug: First I am posting here because for some reason the button to create a bug never appears when I go to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs !

Facebook test users don't behave exactly like real users: If you make a call to graph api fql using a page access token to retrieve basic info for the user like name etc the api returns nothing. The reason why I am using a page access token is because I am making a batch request which requires the page access token. Real users users return the basic info like name with the page access token but test user don't.

Thanks

Comment: It has been posted here several times already: The “create a new bug report” option should appear on the bottom of the list once you start typing into the search box …

Comment: Is this a question? Why would you be using a page access token to access a test user's profile information?

Comment: I explain in the text why I'm using page access token, its because I'm making a batch request which requires it. Thanks